# what will happen when the Class requested some WebService is not in the memory when receiving the response?

Tags: objective-c

what will happen when the Class requested some WebService/Streaming  is not in the memory when receiving the response?

Comment: Can you aceppt my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You will get an exception, you have to keep that class allocated if you want the method to be called.